# Radio Buttons with X-editable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've recently started using http://vitalets.github.io/x-editable/ with jQueryUI.

I successfully used it with input text and select menus, and next wish to implement radio buttons.  The UX should be the same as with other input types (i.e. user clicks some text, two or more radio buttons popup along with a enter and cancel icon).

Is this possible, and if so, how?

Comment: All possible. But you'd better to try to implement something by yourself and ask about a particular problem which you encountered with.

Comment: http://codepen.io/mitchmc/pen/pebIx  try this, once it helps me for custom radio

Comment: @phts.  Guess everything is possible :)  I don't think it currently has this functionality, however, and I will need to create my own script.

Answer (score 1):

The following script works as necessary...

https://gist.github.com/taivo/da6d47c7b291f71b9502